# In React Dev Tools Profiler Flamegraph, what is an "Insertion" component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-devtools

If I run the React dev tools profiler, and then look at the flamegraph, I can see various react components and their rendering times. Such as

```
ForwardRef(DataGridPremium) (<0.1ms of 1996ms)
GridContextProvider (<0.1ms of 1996ms)
MuiTextFieldRoot (<0.1ms of 229ms)
```

But there is also an item listed as if it was a react component, called `Insertion`, with a render time:

```
Insertion (528ms of 528ms)
```

It looks like this in a flamegraph, with an orange background:

[image: Screenshot of a react dev tools profiler flamegraph, with the Insertion component having an orange background]

I've found nothing in the react docs, the react dev tool docs, or on google. Many results bring me to `useInsertionEffect` but I don't think that's related as we have statically compiled CSS to the best of my understanding.

What is this `Insertion`? Is it a component? I obviously could guess that it means the time to insert DOM nodes, but I don't want to make assumptions. There's no components in our codebase that match this name, nor in our libraries it seems, from a grep.

Edit: I did find this in `@mui/material/umd/material-ui.development.js:4730`, perhaps it's that? I'd like to find a way to confirm that if possible, so I can investigate why it's our longest time to render thing.

```
  var Insertion = function Insertion(_ref) {
    ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a component from Emotion (the CSS-in-JS library MUI uses). See more here: https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/blob/main/packages/styled/src/base.js#L27